# HTTP packet decoder/reader

Tags: http, decode

i need a c program to decode http packets. can someone help me or refer to some pointers.

Thanks in Advance.
Raj.

Comment: `0x3A28213A`, `0x6339392C`, `0x7363682E`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading up [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) but RFCs tend to be hard to read. As a starting point this site helped me write my webserver: [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/). Hope it helps you.